# AngularJS wrapping cordova permissions into a promise chain?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-permissions, angular-promise

And just when I think I have my head wrapped around promises I try to implement something and stumble in such a way that makes me realize I don't fully understand Angular yet.

Arrgh!

I am initializing my app and creating an Init Controller and Service factory to ask the user to set permissions the app will need.  However, in the .factory I can't figure out how to create the sequence of promises correctly.  I want to sequentially ask the user and thus am creating a promise chain.

```
Promise 1 = ask for sms access
   process 1 results
   Promise 2 = ask for GET_ACCOUNTS
      process 2 results
      Promise 3 = ask for GPS
         process 3 results
         return to controller with all results
```

The first Promise is throwing me, because the plugin I am using returns an async on the requesting user permission:

```
function requestReadPermission() {  // from cordova-plugin-sim
// no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
  window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission();
}

return $q(requestReadPermission)
.then(function(status) {
   console.log(status) ; // just see what comes back 
   // do something with status
   function getAccounts() {
      cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestContactsAuthorization() ;
   }
   return $q(getAccounts)
}).then(function(status) {
   console.log(status) ; // just see what comes back 
   // do something with status
   function getGPS() {
      cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization() ;
   }
   return $q(getGPS)
}).then(function(status) {
   console.log(status) ; // just see what comes back 
   // do something with status
   return allResults ;
})
```

Additionally, the second two promises already look to be callback functions...so I don't know if I can implement them the way I want.  They come from `cordova-plugin-diagnostics` and in the documentation are called the following way:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestContactsAuthorization(function(status){
    if(status === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){
        console.log("Contacts use is authorized");
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});

cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
    switch(status){
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
            console.log("Permission not requested");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
            console.log("Permission granted");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
            console.log("Permission denied");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
            console.log("Permission permanently denied");
            break;
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnostic plugin functions must be passed a callback function to receive the async result from the native part of the plugin. 
However, you can wrap this in a way to make it Angular-friendly by returning a promise which is resolved by the outcome of the two async callbacks.
For example:

```
function myFunction(){
    var q = $q.defer();
    var statuses = {};
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestContactsAuthorization(function(status){
        console.log('contacts: '+status);
        statuses['contacts'] = status;
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
            console.log('location: '+status);
            statuses['location'] = status;
            q.resolve(statuses);
        });
    });
    return q.promise;
}
```

You can then call your wrapper function using the Angular-style promise:

```
myFunction().then(function(statuses){
    for(var permission in statuses){
        console.log(permission+' is '+statuses[permission]);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, I knew the callbacks were throwing me off.  How would you incorporate the 'sim' permissions too?  I was looking for a cordova-plugins-diagnostic that would allow for me to access the sim card but haven't found one - thus I was using the cordova-plugin-sim to get sim info - but the sim's request permission implementation is an async popup with no call back on it.    btw - thanks for your help.  I was going in the right direction but was def way off track.